# Editing a template in SSRS

Tags: templates, reporting-services

I have a template that needs to be edited (new logo and color scheme).

I cannot find a way to edit the current template.   The template is located in "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\ProjectItems\ReportProject", however when I try to open the template, I get an error.

I cannot open it in SSRS by going to File >> Open.

Searching on the internet did not show me how to edit an existing template, only how to create a new one.

I am currently using visual studio 2010.

Answer (score 0):

I will go around. First create a project in your visual studio and add your template as existing item to your reports. Edit the report and save it back to the desired folder.